# right align digits in pdf python report lab

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, tkinter, reportlab

I am trying to make a pdf out of the results from a python script. Report lab is used. A list containing Months of an year is there. Another list created through user input, containing income pertaining to each month is there. When it is printed to pdf using a forloop, I failed to RIGHT align the amounts.  Part of the code is shown below.

```
def func_makepdf(): 
    c = canvas.Canvas("incometaxreportlabtest.pdf")
    c.drawString(50,800,"INCOME TAX CALCULATIONS FOR THE FINANCIAL YEAR 2020-21")
    c.drawString(50,785,"Name: "+str(v1))
    c.drawString(300,785,"PAN:"+str(v2))
    c.drawString(50,770,"Income Details:")
    v=765
    for i in income_list:
        v=v-10
        c.drawString(50,v-10,str(i))
    vinc=765
    for i in entry_list:
        vinc=vinc-10
        c.drawString(200,vinc-10,'{:>10,.2f}'.format(int(i.get())))
        c.drawString(250,770,"Deduction Details:")


    vdl=765
    for k in deduction_list:
        vdl=vdl-10
        c.drawString(280,vdl-10,k)

    
##                 
    vded=765
    for i in entryded_list:
        vded=vded-10
        c.drawString(400,vded-10,i.get())

    c.save()
```

Comment: Which library are you using to create a PDF? Tkinter does not support output to PDF directly. Your use of the Canvas widget with a pdf name is not a way to convert to PDF.

Comment: Use `drawRightString()` instead.

Comment: @scotty3785 OP has already said that `reportlab` is used.

Comment: @acw1668 Ah, Can't see the API for report lab.

Comment: Use drawRightString() instead. – acw1668 5 hours ago
This solved my problem. Thanks to all who turned with a response! @acw1668